# How do I correctly use inheritence in this framework

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an abstract class ChildNode

```
public abstract class ChildNode {
    public abstract boolean activate()
    public abstract void execute();
}
```

and an abstract class ParrentNode

```
public abstract class ParentNode extends ChildNode {
    public ArrayList<ChildNode> nodes;
    public void execute(){
        for ( ChildNode node : nodes) {
            if (node.activate()) {
                node.execute();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would run this

```
ArrayList<ParentNode> masterNodeArray = null;
//add and create a bunch of nodes implementing different activate methods for both Child/Parent Nodes, and execute methods for child nodes
for (ParentNode node : masterNodeArray) {
        if (node.activate()) {
            node.execute();
            break;
        }
}
```

My issue is, I want parent nodes and child nodes to be able to be part of `ParentNode` -> `nodes` array.  So when it loops through the `nodes` array in the execute function in the `ParentNode` it will handle both parents and children nodes in the array.  So if it reaches a ParentNode, it will handle it as a ParentNode, running the predefined execute function and knowing it has a `nodes` member to loop through as well if it get executed, and if it reaches a ChildNode, it will run the defined execute/activate methods.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Try a `List<ChildNode>` as this can contain parent and child nodes.

Comment: @lexicore my current code for `ParentNode` will assume that everything is a child node.

Comment: usually children extend parents

Comment: @payloc I agree, but in this case, parents require a list and children do not.  So it wouldn't make any sense in this situation

Comment: @PeterLawrey An `Array<ChildNode>` can contain both as well, it just converts a ParentNode to a ChildNode.  It will compile, but it will not behave correctly

Comment: @jacksons5j This is still not a question.

Comment: @lexicore how do I fix my code so it will behave as I explain in the closing paragraph

Comment: Java has no support for converting objects, so this won't happen. What do you mean `it will not behave correctly`

Comment: @jacksons5j Your code should behave as you explain in the closing paragraph, what makes you think it doesn't? Also, I would make `execute()` `final` in `ParentNode` so that a concrete `ParentNode` doesn't override it and prevent it from running all `execute` on all its `ChildNode`s.

Comment: What are you making this for?

Comment: I second @xtratic , your code shoud work just the way it is.

Comment: @boobalangnanasekaran Thanks, I just found though that his problem is not related to inheritance. He was `break`ing in the loop to execute the children of a parent node.

Answer (score 1):

**Your issue was that you were `break`ing in the loop to `execute` all of the `ChildNode`s in the `ParentNode`s list of children**

```
public abstract class ChildNode {
    private boolean activated = true;

    public final boolean isActivated() {
        return activated;
    }

    public final void setActivated(boolean activated) {
        this.activated = activated;
    }

    public abstract void execute();
}

public class ParentNode extends ChildNode {
    private List<ChildNode> children = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override public final void execute() {
        for (ChildNode node : children) {
            if (node.isActivated()) {
                node.execute();
                // DON'T BREAK HERE
            }
        }
    }

    public final List<ChildNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}

public class ConcreteChildNode extends ChildNode {

    private final String name;

    public ConcreteChildNode(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override public void execute() {
        System.out.println("ConcreteChildNode-" + name);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ParentNode parent1 = new ParentNode();
        parent1.getChildren().add(new ConcreteChildNode("1"));
        parent1.getChildren().add(new ConcreteChildNode("2"));

        ParentNode parent2 = new ParentNode();
        parent2.getChildren().add(new ConcreteChildNode("3-1"));
        parent2.getChildren().add(new ConcreteChildNode("3-2"));

        parent1.getChildren().add(parent2);

        parent1.getChildren().add(new ConcreteChildNode("4"));

        parent1.execute();

        // prints
        // ConcreteChildNode-1
        // ConcreteChildNode-2
        // ConcreteChildNode-3-1
        // ConcreteChildNode-3-2
        // ConcreteChildNode-4
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a bot, which is what it looks like.. do it like this

```
public interface Action {
    boolean active()
    boolean execute();
}

public abstract class Controller implements Action {
    public List<Action> nodes;
    public void execute(){
        for (Action node : nodes) {
            if (node.activate()) {
                node.execute();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


public class Operator {
    public List<Controller> nodes;
    public void execute(){
        for (Controller node : nodes) {
            if (node.activate()) {
                node.execute();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```